# Samsung laptop randomly shuts down

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, shutdown, cooling

I have a [Samsung R560](http://www.laptopsdirect.co.uk/Samsung_R560_Laptop_NP-R560-AS02UK/version.asp#specs) laptop that is overheating, and shutting itself down under load consistently.

Here are my load/idle temps from Speedfan:

[image]

*Ignore "Temp1 and Temp2", whatever sensors they are, they're always random.*

The load temperature is after just 5 minutes of playing Fallout 3 - another 5 minutes and it (the GPU - 9600M GS) consistently breaches the mid 90's then shuts down, so it's hard to get a good picture of it.

I'm looking for a solution or some way to decrease these temperatures, because they seem far too high even when idle.

I've tried:

- Opening up the case and clearing all dust with compressed air
- Updating the drivers for my graphics card
- Using a [notebook cooler](http://notebook-cooling.com/2009/09/enermax-cp001-notebook-cooler-review/)

I don't want to:

- Undervolt / underclock (defeats the point of having a more expensive card)
- Use lower power / performance settings (again, I might as well have bought something cheaper)

**Is there anything else I can try (software or inexpensive hardware) that can help me fix this?**

**Has anybody had a Samsung laptop and knows if this can be sorted under my warranty, and the turnaround time of sending it off (UK?)**(it has always ran hotter than it should, but now at 6 months old is getting hot enough to power off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)?  I use that on my desktop and it gives different internal temps

Comment: Thanks! Does the job perfectly, now i know for sure it's an overheating dealio and not something else. The little flame pictures scare me..

Comment: Don't blindly follow what it reports though.  Some machines seem to have sensors that return garbage.  Got a machine here that reports very high RAM temps all the time, but they're actually cool.

Answer (score 4):

You could try applying a little more thermal paste to the processor, but I wouldn't recommend it, and it might just make things worse, to say nothing of voiding the warranty.

**Edit**: As Hyperslug mentions, it could be thermal adhesive, which will pose much more of a problem in that it can be somewhat difficult to remove.

Your best bet would be to call up the company who issued it and have it returned under warranty. Ask them to replace it first, but if the next one behaves in the same fashion, ask for a refund.

Comment: For people who have n owarranty left/are more confident with electonics, remove the CPU, remove all the thermal tranasfer paste form CPU and heatsink using dry, lint free, ESD safe cloth, then put fresh paste on cpu, and reinstall heatsink.  Will fix desktops with similar instability problems too.

Comment: True, but you do want to be careful - too much will make the problem worse, and not enough will also make the problem worse.

Comment: I'm more worried about the GPU than the CPU, are they similarly re-pasteable? I've only ever done this with CPU's on tower-case pc's, can this be *easily* done with a laptop GPU heatsink/fan?

I don't wanna go try rip it off only to find it's unremoveable.

Comment: It might also be a thermal adhesive instead of paste.  I swore I was going to crack the CPU the last time I pried one of those off.

Comment: That's a very good point.

Comment: Poor assembling of your laptop during manufacturing. The Thermal compound has dried up. Rather than trying to put thermal compound (Arctic Silver 5) yourself ina laptop, return the product as defective. However, if oyu want to put thermal compound yourself, you can do it. BUT, you should also re-install your operating system and make sure the hard drive remains constantly defragmented if over used. You can Task Schedule hard drive check every 15 days (CHKDSK /F C:) to make sure large file reading and writing do not corrupt the hard drive sectors.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this and whilst not a technical answer, it will resolve the problem:

Take it back, it is defective. I have used a few Samsung laptops and they are very reliable. This is abnormal behaviour and you shouldn't need to buy anything additional to make it work and run normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have occasional spontaneous-reboots that crop up on a desktop system.  No BSOD, no error log entries, just happy computing and then suddenly I'm staring at the BIOS POSTing.  It's very possibly hardware related, very possibly overheating.  But for some reason, this fix always works:

**Reinstalling the latest DirectX redistributable.**

I'm on WinXP SP2, so for me that's v9.0c-mar2009.  It's a temporary fix -- I might get as much as a month of uptime before something makes my system go haywire -- but now if I see more than one spontaneous reboot in a day I'll re-run the DirectX setup and everything gets better for another week or four.

I've even got a third-party defragmenter that lets me defrag individual files, and I can defrag every other file on C: -- but if I defrag any of DirectX's files, I'm in for a reboot storm within a day.

I've no idea why this works for me, but it does.  It can't hurt you to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the laptop's fan is running and not plugged?  Many fans have a crappy little foam plastic filter--if dust bunnies cover that, especially on a laptop, heat can build up very fast. If the R560's fan is not blowing a hard enough to feel easily on a dry finger, that may well be the problem.

Hm ... one review says the fan is [completely silent](http://www.notebookcheck.net/User-Review-Samsung-R560-Madril-Notebook.11531.0.html), so you might not notice if it stopped running.  I think that's the first thing I'd check.  The case fan is way easier to replace than the CPU fan and thermal paste, too.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with this is easily solvable :D... when you are playing from mains, remove your battery and the temp will go down, 15 degrees easy.

Comment: Going out on a limb, I'm guessing you followed this methodology, hence why you haven't been seen since. That being said, how are your temps? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is really  the best solution for such issue:

First you have to know that the problem is because of the NVIDIA Graphic software
you probably reinstall windows system and you don't have Samsung manufacture recovery . however the solution is regarding to the same description.

so how to be solved?
First, you need to uninstall NVIDIA from your computer.

Second go to http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP-Q430H
depend of your laptop Model mine was NP-Q430H.
anyway if you didn't register your laptop in Samsung official site  you can do that anytime. 
the reason why you need to do so is because to download the drivers matching  your laptop.

Third, go to view all beside the downloads and expand the list-box, select the drivers option

Fourth,you will see a list of drivers. Pick the internal VGA drive and download all of other important drivers.  its good to save them in computer so you can install them whenever you need them.

Note: after you uninstall NVIDIA  THE SYSTEM ASK YOU TO RESTART WINDOWS DON'T YOU DO SO.

Finally install your drivers and restart WINDOWS and you will see everything is working wEll.

THANK YOU FOR WATCHING...